# c# and c++ memory address

Tags: c#, pointers, interop, pinvoke

I am using DllImport to receive data from an external DLL. I receive the data using the following structure in C#

```
public struct EventBuffer
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = CSTA_MAX_HEAP)]
    public byte[] data;
};
```

So far I have been able to work with everything I have received from this DLL. However one the structures I receive has pointer inside (C++)

```
typedef struct ConnectionList_t {

_Int             count;
//Connection_t    FAR *connection;
Connection_t FAR * POINTER_32 connection;
} ConnectionList_t;
```

When I parse the byte[] in C# I get an address instead of the array itself. So I have tried to access that memory address with the code below. But the result is not what I expected, I know that the data is valid as my C++ test program receives right values

```
Int32 pointerToAddress = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 4);       
IntPtr intPtr = new IntPtr(pointerToAddress);
byte[] luckyYou = new byte[2048];
Marshal.Copy(intPtr, luckyYou, 0, lenghtOfMarshalledStructure);
```

Am I missing something to access a memory address received from C++?

Comment: This looks like an `IntPtr` to me

Comment: This is not safe - on 64-bit, the pointer will be 8 bytes long instead of 4. Also, is `Connection_t` a struct? Also, if you're already using C++ anyway, why not do the marshalling in C++/CLI?